# From my website some one sending an email to one email address continuously one after another

Tags: magento-1.9, email, security

From my website some one is sending an email to one email address continuously one after another. I cant find where it is sending from , I use the SMTPPro extension to send emails.

The email contents are some advertisements i t also  will change continuously.

I have attached a screenshot of the email below.

[image: email]

the Reply-To address always changes but the from address is the same (the Magento general contact address)

Answer (score 4):

I belive that you had setup a customer feedback form or some contact form in the website. Try to enable captcha in backend and see the changes.
u can enable captcha by :

> Go to system > configuration > customers > customer configuration > CAPTCHA and Enable CAPTCHA.

Comment: @AkhilKurian welcome ! pls mark this as answer